# RVM with ruby 1.9.2 error: no such file to load config/boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, rvm, ruby-1.9.2

I cannot seem to figure this out.  I am new to the unix environment, so hopefully this will be an easy issue to solve.  The issue is, when i'm in the home directory and any directory after, rails cannot find config/boot and I cannot run any rails commands.  I tried nuking the rvm install (with rvm implode) and reinstalling it via the rvm website.  These issues do not exist if I am before the home directory (ie, i am in ~/ and I cd .., then run rails -v, everything works fine)

When I'm in my home directory (~/ and beyond), I get an error when trying any rails commands (ie rails -v) (note - rvm use system rails works fine):

```
macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ rails -v
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- /Users/dannykirschner/config/boot (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

It seems there is a pathing issue with boot, and I am not sure how to fix that.

More info:

```
    macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ which ruby
    /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
    macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ which rails
    /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rails

    macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

And to make it more puzzling, with 1.8.7, I can get the rails command to work, but only if I specify a gemset.  rails is also installed in the global gemset.

```
    macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ rvm use 1.8.7
Using /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334
macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ rails -v
script/rails:5:in `require': no such file to load -- /Users/dannykirschner/config/boot (LoadError)
    from script/rails:5

    macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ rvm use 1.8.7@2.3.11
Using /Users/dannykirschner/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334 with gemset 2.3.11
macbook-4:~ dannykirschner$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.11
```

Any help is appreciated!